# Print Variables in For Loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, matplotlib, networkx

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
T10,T11,T12,T13 = nx.random_tree(10),nx.random_tree(11),nx.random_tree(12),nx.random_tree(13)
T = [T10,T11,T12,T13]
for t in T: 
    print("The Pruefer Code for -",  pruefer_code(t))
    fig = figure()
    axis = fig.add_subplot(111)
    nx.draw(t, **opts, ax = axis)
```

Which results in:

```
The Pruefer Code for -  [2, 8, 1, 9, 5, 5, 6, 8]
The Pruefer Code for -  [9, 6, 10, 7, 4, 8, 10, 4, 6]
The Pruefer Code for -  [4, 1, 4, 8, 11, 11, 8, 3, 4, 8]
The Pruefer Code for -  [8, 7, 11, 4, 2, 7, 9, 1, 5, 10, 7]
```

Plus the graphs - how would I amend the code so it'd say:

```
The Pruefer Code for - T10 [2, 8, 1, 9, 5, 5, 6, 8]
The Pruefer Code for - T11 [9, 6, 10, 7, 4, 8, 10, 4, 6]
The Pruefer Code for - T12 [4, 1, 4, 8, 11, 11, 8, 3, 4, 8]
The Pruefer Code for - T13 [8, 7, 11, 4, 2, 7, 9, 1, 5, 10, 7]
```

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: @mightyandweakcoder `t` is a variable with values, doing `str(t)` wont return `T10` etc.. it will transform the entire variable to a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
T10,T11,T12,T13 = nx.random_tree(10),nx.random_tree(11),nx.random_tree(12),nx.random_tree(13)
T = [T10,T11,T12,T13]
for i, t in enumerate(T): 
    print("The Pruefer Code for - T1{:}".format(i),  pruefer_code(t))
    fig = figure()
    axis = fig.add_subplot(111)
    nx.draw(t, **opts, ax = axis)
```

The [`enuemerate`](https://realpython.com/python-enumerate/) will return the element in a list as well as an index ([0,3]). Then adding to the `print` the constant string `T1` while you adds the current index `i` to the string will give the desired result (using [`format`](https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/)).